# Android Studio - Can't Read preferenceSettings

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save user's language using SharedPreference. MainActivity is my main activity and SettingsActivity is where I ask and save user's language.

Saving:

```
private SharedPreferences preferenceSettings;
private SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditor;
private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE = 0;
public void save(String lg){
    preferenceSettings = getPreferences(PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
    preferenceEditor = preferenceSettings.edit();
    preferenceEditor.putString("language", lg);
    preferenceEditor.commit();
    finish();
}
```

Reading:

```
preferenceSettings = getPreferences(PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
String LanguageS = preferenceSettings.getString("language", "0");
```

with this code, I can successfully save and read from same activity(SettingsActivity) but when I return to my main activity, I can't read.

I am using this code to read from my main activity but it always returns "0".

```
private SharedPreferences preferenceSettings;
private SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditor;
private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE = 0;
private static String Lang = "0";

preferenceSettings = getPreferences(PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
Lang = preferenceSettings.getString("language", "0");
```

What am I doing wrong? I am controlling these lines for almost 1 hour but couldn't find any mistakes.

Comment: Please post you getPreferences() method.

Comment: He probably uses the [getPreferences(int mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29) from the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using [getPreferences(int mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29), you should use the [getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int))

If you read the java doc on the `getPreferences(int mode)` it says:

```
Retrieve a {@link SharedPreferences} object for accessing preferences
that are private to this activity. 

This simply calls the underlying
{@link #getSharedPreferences(String, int)} method by 
passing in this activity's class name as the preferences name. @param
mode Operating mode.  

Use {@link #MODE_PRIVATE} for the default
operation, {@link #MODE_WORLD_READABLE} and {@link
MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE} to control permissions.
@return Returns the single SharedPreferences instance that can be used
to retrieve and modify the preference values.
```

Comment: Thanks dude. My bad. I guess I need some sleep now. I used this thing before but after 3 months later, just couldn't remember. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

This is happening beacuse, the method that you're using `getPreferences(PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE)`

returns the preferences saved by `Activity's class name` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29) :

> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are private to this activity. This simply calls the underlying getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's class name as the preferences name.

So, when you're saving the prefs in `SettingsActivity` it's being saved under the name `"SettingsActivity"`

but when you're getting the prefs in `MainActivity` it's returning you the prefs saved under name `"MainActivity"`

So, you should use [getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) method with the same name instead.