# Load SharePrefs Value into textview

Tags: java, android-studio, sharedpreferences

So i made a game with a simple score keeping system, It seems that the highscore gets put into the shared prefs correctly, but when trying to load the high score into the activity oncreate the application crashes. this is my code.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int score = sharedPref.getInt("SCORE", 0);
    String score2 = Integer.toString(score);
    text10.setText(score2);
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong so any advice will be great!

Here is my save score code

```
private void savePref(String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putInt(key, value);
    edit.apply();
}
```

Comment: please share the stacktrace

Comment: what is a stacktrace?

Comment: error that's coming in the log

Comment: it must be some parse exception. Please share log as have requested.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of the log to insert

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: your `text10` object is null, initialize it and the prob will be solved

Comment: problem was i was calling the method before ive declared the objects. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log you have shared, it is clear that you have not get the TextView properly. Assuming that you have set the layout, do something like this:

```
    text10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int score = sharedPref.getInt("SCORE", 0);
    String score2 = Integer.toString(score);
    text10.setText(score2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save [SharedPreferences](http://%20%20%20%20%20SharedPreferences%20sharedPreferences%20=%20context.getSharedPreferences(%22DATA%22,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);%20%20%20%20%20sharedPreferences.edit().putString(%22STRENGTH%22,yourVar).apply();%20%20Then%20get%20it%20out%20using:%20%20%20%20%20%20SharedPreferences%20sharedPreferences%20=%20context.getSharedPreferences(%22DATA%22,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);%20%20%20%20%20strength%20=%20sharedPreferences.getString(%22STRENGTH%22,null);%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) properly, using both name and mode

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("DATA",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening beacuse, the method that you're using `getPreferences(PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE)`

returns the preferences saved by `Activity's class name` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29) :

> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are private to this activity. This simply calls the underlying getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's class name as the preferences name.

So, when you're saving the prefs in `SomeActivity` it's being saved under the name `"SomeActivity"`

but when you're getting the prefs in this activity it's returning you the prefs saved under this activity's class name.

So, you should use [getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) method with the same name instead.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145589/android-studio-cant-read-preferencesettings/38145944#38145944)

**UPDATE**

After looking at the stacktrace looks like your `TextView` object `text10` is `null`, initialize it and the problem will be solved.

Comment: is it possible that its returning an error because at first launch no value has been saved yet?

Comment: No, if the value is not saved, it will return the default value given which is 0 in your case `sharedPref.getInt("SCORE", 0);` , btw in which activity are you storing "SCORE". same activity or different?